# How get information about source of Windows Shortcut using NIO?

Tags: java, windows, nio, symlink, nio2

Please look at this code snippet:

```
        Path path = Paths.get("followLink.lnk");
        System.out.println("path:" + path.toRealPath());
        System.out.println("path:" + path.toRealPath(LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS));
```

file with name followLink.lnk was created using following windows action:

mouse right click on file -> create shortcut

last two rows output are same and this information about shortcut. Is there way in nio2 obtain information about of source are pointed of shortcut ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toRealPath` is for resolving symbolic links. Windows shortcuts are not symbolic links. You will have to open the `.lnk` file and read its contents to figure out where it points to.

Comment: Is there way in windows create symbolic link?

Comment: @gstackoverflow [Windows NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) (2003+?) supports symbolic links, hardlinks, and directory junctions. See [`mklink`](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/278262-mklink-create-use-links-windows.html) (I would expect the symbolic links to be supported under Java, but I've never tried.)

Comment: Messed situation about symbolic links and shortcuts